# In the last year, did Airbus make any changes to existing or newly built A220s control panels or AT/AP software?

Tags: safety, faa, airbus, airbus-a220

As reported in various places (e.g. by [simplyflying.com](https://simpleflying.com/airbus-a220-inadvertent-autopilot-engagement-near-misses/)), there were two near-catastrophes in the A220, not because of the [widely-discussed engine topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/102182/scared-of-flying-in-an-airbus-a220)¹, but because of how autopilot & autothrottle works in combination with the fact that they're right next to each other on the control panel.

Both CAR and FAA responded by issuing their own [EAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergency_airworthiness_directive) (PDF links: [CAR's EAD](https://wwwapps.tc.gc.ca/Saf-Sec-Sur/2/cawis-swimn/AD_dl.aspx?ad=CF-2022-64&cn=CF&ft=pdf&l=E), [FAA's EAD](http://avherald.com/files/2022-25-51_Emergency.pdf)) requiring an addition to the handbook to keep pilots from trying to engage either AP or AT too early. The FAA makes it very clear in their EAD they consider this only an *interim* measure.

My question is:

- Have Airbus since changed anything to remedy the situation beyond the addition to the handbook? A hardware change to the control panel (such as moving on or both of the buttons) or a software change to the AP or AT features (such as refusing to engage below the 400ft limit mentioned by both EADs?
- And if not, what are there in the way of rules, regulations or legislation to compel them to do so in a timely manner?

---

*¹ (I'm writing this question after getting curious in the comments of that ASE question and being encouraged there to do so)*